# Access: How to Check conditions of more than one field in a single statement

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form that I want to close.

The form has 2 unbound text boxes named:

- `ExpName`
- `ExpAmount`

The form has 2 buttons named:

- `btnCloseExp`
- `btnSaveExp`

The idea is when the user clicks the close button I want to check whether `ExpName` and `ExpAmount` are equal to `""` and if not, I want to display a `MsgBox` to ask whether to save before closing.

Is there a way to do this check in one `if` statement or `case` statement? I used the below `Msgbox` to check whether the `if` statement is working or not, but this doesn't seem to work:

```
   If Me.ExpName And Me.ExpAmount <> "" Then
      MsgBox "there is data in the fields"
   End If
```

Comment: Try: `If Me.ExpName <> "" And Me.ExpAmount <> "" Then
      MsgBox "there is data in the fields"
   End If`

Comment: MiguelH, thank you very much, it worked. thank you very much for the quick reply!